# How to encrypt mysql database?

Tags: mysql, encryption, plugins, mautic

I want to encrypt mysql database so when someone open phpmyadmin data is encrypted.I want to do without changing code at application layer.
I already try key ring plugin but it's not work with table or column level

Comment: try this https://serverfault.com/questions/538715/whats-a-good-way-to-encrypt-a-mysql-database-and-is-it-worth-it

Comment: I don't want to change query and code .is there any method available.

Comment: method means other way or db method

Comment: Yes db method. Question is that make database encrypted without changing code and sql query

Comment: whole database or specific table or column

Comment: Both database + column

Comment: If you want a magical pony that can do this, Stack Overflow can't help. What you're asking for is not possible. If you encrypt in such a fashion that a database client like phpMyAdmin can't see the data then you **must** change the application code.

Answer (score 3):

This is an absolutely impossible objective.

phpmyadmin accesses the data in the database using *exactly* the same mechanisms as your application code -- nothing more, nothing less.  If the data were encrypted from phpmyadmin's perspective, it would also be encrypted from the application's perspective, and the application in its current state would be unable to use it.